# What is the motivation for a law requiring 2 parties to consent for recording a conversation

Tags: law

I asked this question in the law site, but I was told it has more to do with politics ([same question in the law site)](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/38939/what-is-the-motivation-between-the-2-parties-recording-consent-laws).

Let's assume A and B have a discussion about a business deal and A will record the conversation without B's knowledge. Later on, they have a disagreement that takes them to court. Let's also assume that the recording is long enough to be unambiguous and can't be taken out of context.

In some states, B should consent to the recording but I fail to understand the motivation behind that law:

- A is already 'recording' the conversation in his brain. It may be a fuzzy and somewhat unreliable recording, but the conversation is nonetheless saved somewhere.
- If the court is trying to establish 'the truth', nothing could be better than a recording of the situation; why rely on 2 fuzzy biased recollections of the events when a single recording will provide reliable information.
- One could argue that if A is wrong, he will not produce the recording, but if he's right he will product it, therefore B is at a disadvantage; but maybe A has a much better memory than B, or vice versa, so there is no true equality when it comes to event recollection and we'd just be adding a lot of random to the process.
- A could think that since he's not allowed to produce a recording, he could do a transcript of his memory, aided by the audio recording; but since he knows the 'truth', having his testimony valued at the same level as B's pure memory recollection is putting A as a disadvantage since B's memory, not matter how good, wouldn't rival a recording.

I can't understand the motivation of 2 consents at all. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: I'm not sure what tag to add to this, I think only the law tag doesn't cover it but I'm not sure what other tags fit. If you want to add another tag, please feel free to add a comment.

Comment: It's related to illegal eavesdropping or wiretapping. Can you elaborate on what the [relevant wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_call_recording_laws) doesn't cover well enough?

Comment: Stopping stuff from being taken out of context and/or proving it wasn't taken out of context is probably the entire point of the law, so your assumption about the recording being unambiguous is a hard one to make. "Why aren't guns allowed on planes? Let's assume they won't be used for hijacking it".

Comment: @Thomas You seem to be asking from a purely "How will it help the legal system" point of view, but you need to consider non-legal abuses of recordings. They could be used for blackmail or to embarrass or humiliate someone, and there are privacy considerations. I once associated with someone who recorded everything; he occasionally got out humorous, embarrassing recordings to poke fun at people, often using quotes out of context. I refused to associate with the person after that, as I should not have to put up with that nonsense. You need to consider more than just the court ramifications.

Comment: @Aaron, point taken; I didn't really think out of the legal context.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy, the wiki page is listing the laws per country, but there is no content about the reasoning behind them.

Comment: A bit unrelated, but does anyone know how you're supposed to know the location of the callee? Especially given that nowadays area codes have little to do with your location...

Comment: Does your question exclude the case of recording with the intent of making the recording accessible to third parties or even of publishing the recording? Because in these cases, it is clearly a matter of privacy. What I say to one person, I say under the assumption of a certain extent of confidentiality. I would speak differently if I knew I wasn't talking to you alone but potentially also to the press, my employer, the police, my enemies, all my friends and family members.

Comment: @henning, my question was asked in the context of a court case, where I failed to understand why a full discussion recorded from end to finish, that I deemed unambiguous (but as others have pointed out, it's not so black and white) could not be accepted as evidence. As answers and discussions diverged a bit, I think there have been a lot of interesting points raised. But, to answer your question, I didn't think about the aspect of publishing the recording when I posted the question.

Comment: Relevant, but not considered so far.  The situation where person C is making a recording.

Comment: I wonder if it's more that's it's just illegal to record someone without their knowledge / consent for privacy reasons? And then in court, you can't produce evidence that was illegally obtained, similar to how the police can't use evidence that was gotten from a search of your house without a warrant even if that evidence is incontrovertible.

Answer (score 35):

If I know you are recording me, I may speak differently and use clearer language. If I don't, I may be more likely to use ambiguous language that can be taken out of context. Consider the case of [James O'Keefe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_O%27Keefe) and Project Veritas. Their goal is to surreptitiously record people doing things some people may think are bad and discredit them for political purposes. As it turns out, selective editing of the recordings caused a massive uproar on a number of issues when in fact the context surrounding the recorded exchanges was sometimes hotly disputed after editing, and in some cases demonstrably false.

Numerous undercover investigations by would-be reporters at factory farms attempted to [highlight the conditions](https://mercyforanimals.org/investigations) of animals at those places, inspiring a wave of [Ag-gag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ag-gag) laws in some states and other anti-whistleblower legislation. In some cases they were [successful](https://www.wral.com/undercover-video-leads-to-charges-against-chicken-farm-worker/15168454/) at being truthful and highlighting abuse, in others they were only successful at hurting their cause since legislators in those areas weren't convinced of the recordings' veracity given how they were obtained.

Having two-party consent to record interactions means everyone knows a recording exists. If I know a recording exists of me, I would be more likely to request a full unedited copy so that I may protect myself from people who only wish to further their own agenda regardless of what I actually say. If someone has to lie or be deceitful in order to obtain a recording, how can viewers trust that what they see or hear is the full context? A single surreptitious recording can be used to imply a large scale conspiracy and discredit an entire organization, when in reality there could just be a single bad actor.

---

<sub>Note - this issue is distinct and separate from so-called "[ambush journalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journalism_genres#Ambush_journalism)", since generally in those cases large lumbering cameramen are a giveaway that the target is being recorded.</sub>

Comment: This doesn't really make sense when one party has declared recording, even if one party hasn't consented to it.  They will know they have been recorded.  Even when people know they are being recorded they can be taken out of context.

Comment: @opa See the note at the bottom. It is a completely different issue when the recording is done in full view vs when it's done surreptitiously. Continuing an interaction once you know it is being recorded is implicitly consenting to being recorded. I'm not sure if any state laws actually take that into account, though.

Comment: "Continuing an interaction once you know it is being recorded is implicitly consenting to being recorded." Is not noted in your post AFAICS? and the fact that "[you are] not sure if any state laws actually take that into account, though."  means implicit consent here has no legal basis right?, and then we circle back around to how this is a justification of these laws.

Comment: @opa Just because I don't know something does not mean there's no legal basis for that something. Look closer for the first part, and try not to get carried away with trying to find an exact word-for-word match.

Comment: A particularly good example involving Project Veritas is a situation in which an ACORN employee 'played along' with a scam that O' Keefe purported to run, and then called the police after O' Keefe left.  The viewer of O' Keefe's footage may take the ACORN employee at face value and assume he was facilitating the scam.  It turns out that hidden recordings can be used to make honest citizens look like accessories to fraud. 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACORN_2009_undercover_videos_controversy

Comment: Downvoted for the baseless claim that Project Veritas do "selective editing of the recordings" because they always offer the full, unedited versions, and this is merely a myth peddled by political outlets (on the receiving end of said records) like media matters and think progress.

Comment: @SSight3 Maybe they do offer the full versions _somewhere_, I'm not sure, but what they released to media outlets was definitely selectively edited so I welcome your downvote. Have a great day!

Comment: @JeffLambert Examples: https://townhall.com/tipsheet/bethbaumann/2019/02/28/watch-project-veritas-releases-unedited-video-of-van-jones-saying-russia-is-a-nothing-burger-after-cpac-confrontation-n2542425 https://www.projectveritas.com/2014/05/20/full-un-edited-raw-video-exclusive-release-by-project-veritas/

Comment: @JeffLambert "I don't know something does not mean there's no legal basis for that something." there is some sort of misunderstanding, I'll clarify the situation from my pov.  I see your answer, based *on what is there* I don't see how it supports motivation for 2 party consent.  My reasoning is that if one party starts recording and at least communicates that to the other party that they are, then the points raised in your post are moot, since this party will have the same options. ...

Comment: @JeffLambert  You respond with continued interaction once notified implicitly gives consent, then immediately say you have no idea if this is how it actually works legally.  I am not interested in what *would* make sense legally, because if a states don't implement the law in that way, then this justification fails, and we are back to square one, which is: How do you justify when simply announcing recording provides the same benefits?  Also anytime you've pointed to the post in response, it hasn't appeared to obviously address the only interesting thing here, legal standard for implied consent

Comment: @JeffLambert I'm not saying that it *wouldn't* make sense for implied consent to exist, imo it would.  I'm not saying that there is no legal justification for it,*I don't know*, but the fact that *you also don't appear to know* is the crux issue. Providing evidence that implied consent works in the way you describe would prove your point, but AFAICT, this evidence has not been provided. If a law requiring 2 person consent doesn't have your implicit consent, your argument for motivation doesn't work.

Comment: @opa I think I see where you're coming from now, but my experience can only inform me generally when it comes to issues of law. If you want an exact answer with respect to what limitations state laws have regarding implied two party consent I can only suggest asking about it at Law.SE, I can only answer the question here on Politics to the best of my ability. I can say that the general belief is that nobody can force you to say anything, and if you say something after being told you're being recorded that you regret, I don't think you'll get much sympathy.

Comment: I fail to see the relevance of the recordings of animal abuse.  There is no conversation in this case, and probably no recordings of any humans at all.

Comment: @gerrit Certainly not in the dubbed over versions with the Sarah McLachlan sound track, but as they're being recorded it's just someone showing up to work at their workplace with their coworkers. Plenty of humans and conversations sprinkled in.

Comment: @JeffLambert I see.  The animal abuse videos I have seen only show how animals are being held in abusive conditions, with activists entering at night when no (other) humans are present.

Comment: @gerrit You can't get evidence of people actively committing abuse without other people around. The conditions at some of those places are pretty bad, but the worse ones are those depicting what other humans are actively doing. Check out the last source, you don't get that kind of footage at night with no other people around.

Comment: @JeffLambert Actively committing abuse, no.  Passively committing abuse (animals held in abusive conditions), yes.  The clear evidence that Swedish activists took of animal abuse in pig stables was taken at night.  If I enter a pig stable at night then clearly I have evidence of the conditions in which pigs are being held.  Of course, it does not help in court, as long as [animal abuse is legal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_animal_farming).  But this is politics, not law; the aim of the footage is to influence political debate, not to use in court.

Comment: Pretty sure 2-party consent laws existed before Project Veritas or PETA. This doesn't explain the original motivation, so for that I must dock points.

Comment: @Chloe Pedantry aside, they are just examples used to highlight the motivation. PETA is mentioned nowhere in the answer, so do what you think is right. Have a great day!

Answer (score 25):

To pick a two-party-consent jurisdiction at random, let us consider California, USA.

In 1967, the California Legislature enacted a broad, protective invasion-of-privacy statute in response to what it viewed as a serious and increasing threat to
the confidentiality of private communications resulting from then recent advances
in science and technology that had led to the development of new devices and
techniques for eavesdropping upon and recording such private communications.

This was done by means of Assembly Bill 860, which became Penal Code §§ 630-637.2.  [In a statement](https://books.google.ca/books?id=SUhMAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA8-IA33&dq=california%20assembly%20bill%20no%20860%201967&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJg9m_p8PhAhUJiVQKHdSGATYQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=california%20assembly%20bill%20no%20860%201967&f=false) by [Assemblyman Jesse Marvin "Big Daddy" Unruh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesse_M._Unruh), before the Senate Committee on Judiciary, the bill was so described:

> The Legislature hereby declares that advances in science and
>   technology have led to the development of new devices and techniques
>   for the purpose of eavesdropping upon private communications and that
>   the invasion of privacy resulting from the continual and increasing
>   use of such devices and techniques has created a serious threat to the
>   free exercise of personal liberties and cannot be tolerated in a free
>   and civilized society.  The Legislature by this chapter intends to
>   protect the right of privacy of the people of this state.

This would suggest that the motivation for a law requiring 2 parties to consent for recording a conversation is **a concern for privacy**.

Comment: Your example, which is 99% of your answer, does not seem to apply to this Q&A about 2-party consent since it is about eavesdropping. Unless there is something in the legalese that suggests otherwise, I don't see how you could call 1-party consent eavesdropping. Eavesdropping would be more 0-party consent, no?

Comment: @Aaron: The law explicitly addreses recording of conversations: " 632 (a) A person who, intentionally and without the consent of all parties to a confidential communication, uses an electronic amplifying or recording device to eavesdrop upon or record the confidential communication, whether the communication is carried on among the parties in the presence of one another or by means of a telegraph, telephone, or other device, except a radio, shall be punished [...]" - [California Penal Code, 631](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=PEN&sectionNum=631).

Comment: The way the law is worded, it's more two-party *knowledge* than two-party *consent*. "A person who, intentionally and without the consent of all parties to a confidential communication" and then "confidential communication" is defined as being one in which the parties participate in under the belief that it's not being recorded.

Comment: @Acccumulation Knowledge is an obvious prerequisite of consent, so there is a close relationship. Once there is knowledge of the intent to record a conversation, consent is easily indicated by action: non-consent is expressed by stopping to talk, walking away, hanging up the phone, etc. Consent is expressed by continuing the verbal interaction in the full knowledge it is being recorded.

Comment: Jesse Unruh said "Money is the mother's milk of politics."  And he didn't want anyone to record conversations with him without his permission.  Was this law a pre-emptive strike against anti-corruption investigations?

Answer (score 14):

I think you're starting from wrong assumption:

> A is already 'recording' the conversation in his brain. It may be a fuzzy and somewhat unreliable recording, but the conversation is nonetheless saved somewhere.

One's memory is not equivalent to a record. Your memory is a proof **only to you**, while a record is a proof you can use **to convince others**.

> If the court is trying to establish 'the truth', nothing could be better than a recording of the situation; why rely on 2 fuzzy biased recollections of the events when a single recording will provide reliable information.

The act of observing changes the state of the system being observed. That's not only true for quantum physics but for people as well. A will behave differently: be more reserved and defensive knowing that the conversation is recorded. B will talk more freely and openly. By recording that A knows but B doesn't, the conversation is already biased, because A is talking things that will sound good on tape in court, while B is talking things that sound good in conversation. We are imperfect beings, we don't say things that are true. It can be summed up as: we say things that we imagine the other side wants to hear. **With one-side recording, B is talking to A, but A is talking to the future judge** (or whoever they plan to produce this record to). It's unavoidable that the judge will gravitate towards A.

> One could argue that if A is wrong, he will not produce the recording, but if he's right he will product it, therefore B is at a disadvantage; but maybe A has a much better memory than B, or vice versa, so there is no true equality when it comes to event recollection and we'd just be adding a lot of random to the process.

Now this part puts A at clear advantage. It's not about who remembers it better, it's about who can convince the judge they're right. If A is right, they go to the court and produce the recording. If A relistens the recording and realizes they're wrong - they back down and hide the record. If B goes to the court, court has no way of forcing A to produce the record (your "ultimate source of truth") because nobody knows it exists.

> A could think that since he's not allowed to produce a recording, he could do a transcript of his memory, aided by the audio recording; but since he knows the 'truth', having his testimony valued at the same level as B's pure memory recollection is putting A as a disadvantage since B's memory, not matter how good, wouldn't rival a recording.

That's not any disadvantage. You're stretching it too far. Both A and B represent their recollection about what happened. The fact that A knows for sure their recollection is closer to the truth than B's is annoying and frustrating but that's not a disadvantage. It's B who's at disadvantage, as human memory is imperfect and [we can't tell facts from fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_memory). Or you can say that it's the truth (if it even exists) is at disadvantage.

A can always choose: the not-really-unbiased recording, or human memory/imagination. It's like playing in casino with 2 dice and you get to pick which one everybody gets to honor after the throw. That's huge.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you make a business deal with a person who doesn't consent to it being recorded ?

The issue is not a business deal where you have different takes on what the agreement actually was (and I would strongly suspect that a recording of the conversation would be permissable in court).
The Issue is private conversations that could be a problem in a different way. Like an access hollywood tape as an example (note that there was consent here, obviously, and both of them were wearing a microphone. I just used the incident as an example.).

Comment: What is the point of your example, if they had consented?

Comment: You realize that there's no example where they didn't, for legal reasons. But the point was, obviously, that the things that were said in the tape are the kinds of things the law is supposed to protect you from coming out.

Comment: The point wasn't "obvious" if I had to ask.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is about the *differences* between mutual notification and mutual consent.  Other answers have already pointed out that people behave differently when they know they are being recorded -- which would happen in either case.

Mutual ***consent*** leaves little ambiguity that both parties know the conversation is being recorded.  One party must offer to make a recording, and the other party must actively accept.

In contrast, when the standard is merely mutual ***notification***, it is easy to dispute that adequate notice was not given.  What is adequate language for such a notice?  What if the other party could not hear or does not understand the notice?  Do nonverbal actions such as showing recording equipment qualify as notice?  Because no action is required by the second party, there is a great deal of ambiguity whether notice was adequately given.  In some cases, the second party could simply deny after the fact that notice was given.

The standard of mutual consent therefore reduces disputes between the parties that notice was given.

Answer (score 3):

If I know the conversation is being recorded and you do not I can deliberately steer it to implicate you in things while avoiding implications to myself.

I can also selectively edit the audio after the conversation happens and unless we both have a copy it is hard for me to prove that happened. If both people know it is being recorded and have a copy of the original recording that is fair to both sides.

For example let's say two politicians are talking and you talk about the affair you had in order to get your opponent to talk about your affair. Then afterwords you cut out your own admission and anonymously send the other part to a few reporters. Or even worse take a few snippets out of context (potentially if really sliding down the slippery slope completely re-cut them).

For example "I hear you had an affair", "I deny that". "What do you think about bill X", "That's a complicated question" could be re-cut as "I hear you had an affair", "That's a complicated question" and as only one person has the recording it is hard to prove otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say everyone here more or less assumes that recording can be done only by one party.
So for example editing is easily done as no one can prove it was edited [don't know technicalities behind proving editing].

But getting the advantage because of editing might be as well false. Edited proof might actually lead to loosing case, imprisonment etc, if other party was also recording secretly and this is now proof of dishonesty. So instead of being leverage **is exactly the opposite**.

Since there are laws prohibiting use of recordings, the use of the recordings is not being improved and we all are in the grey area of 'what if'.

I can imagine that idea behind not using recordings **might** be that it **might** divide society more. No one would speak freely anymore in private settings etc. especially if there would be some televised cases of clebs or citizens loosing a lot because of being secretly recorded.
Distrust could be really bad.

I see no reason though, why in business settings it should be ever prohibited. That is the setting that is widely abused by cowboys or too mighty business people anyway - and I think that might be the real reason of no recording laws. Mighty business people would never allow this kind of leverage to anyone.

Comment: While modern digital editing techniques make it possible to do very sophisticated editing that's difficult to prove, I think you'll find that most such laws were crafted long before such techology existed, when recording was primarily done on magnetic tape, and editing consisted of splicing and re-recording. I doubt ease of editing was a factor in the creation of such laws.

Comment: My opinion was very narrow. It mentions only editing, but manipulated use that can be contradicted by other party recordings is ie. Out of context recording, first that comes to my mind. Apart from that whatever was the medium to carry data, there was always editing possibility existing I guess. Plus criminals were usually one step ahead of law as they were trying to invent ways of circumventing a ways of detection of illegal activities...

Answer (score 1):

One big thing not covered yet is that 1 party consent allows recording a person without their consent, while 2 party consent does not.

- 1 party consent means: You are allowed to record people without their consent*.
- 2 party consent means: To record someone you need their consent**.

So the discussion gets down to if lawmakers want to allow people to record themselves and their constituents without their consent, or not. There are plenty of arguments either way, with the main argument in favor of recording without consent being transparency, while the main argument against is fear of slander/extortion.

---

*under limited but rather common circumstances.

**exceptions apply

Answer (score 0):

This law is to protect salesmen, collection agents, contractors, repair shops, etc. from customers who would be able to prove what representations and promises were made if the recording were allowed.  In MA (until a federal court ruling) it served, according to the MA Supreme Judicial Court, to prevent criminals from documenting police misconduct.

Comment: Please add sources to support your answer. You answer is as yet unconvincing that those are the reasons for making such laws.

Comment: I can't see how a law would be enacted to protect criminal action. As @JJJ stated, can you provide sources?

Comment: It would certainly interfere with the ability of many people to do their jobs, including the police, debt collectors, salesmen, and others who might rely on deception or threats to get what they want, as well as exposing doctors, psychiatrists, and other professions to greater risk of malpractice suits. But you offer no proof that this is the motivation; it might be entirely virtuous and right-to-privacy.